# how to add a xml node to a symfony Crawler()

Tags: xml, symfony, web-crawler, dom-node

I need to manage xml documents in saymfony.

I've got no problem to get the xml into a Crawler() instance, modify existing node and after it, put the xml into a file.

But i can't add new node.

When i try to add a new node with appendChild method to the parent, i've got:

> wrong document error

And when i try the add method to the crawler, i've got:

> impossible to add two differents sources to the crawler?

What can i do to add a simple node to an existing crawler?

Thanks for any response

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue to you, I tried:

```
$crawler=new Crawler($someHtml);
$crawler->add('<element />');
```

and got

> Attaching DOM nodes from multiple documents in the same crawler is forbidden.

With a `DOMDocument`, you use its own `createElement` method to make node(s), and then attach them to the document with `appendChild` or whatever. But since `Crawler` doesn't seem to have anything like createElement, the solution I came up with is to initialize the Crawler with a native dom document, do whatever you want to do with the Crawler, but then use the dom document as a "node factory" when you need to add a node.

My particular situation was that I need to check if a document had a `head`, and add one (specifically add it above the body tag) if it didn't:

```
        $doc = new \DOMDocument;
        $doc->loadHtml("<html><body bgcolor='red' /></html>");
        $crawler = new Crawler($doc);
        if ($crawler->filter('head')->count() == 0) {
            //use native dom document to make a head
            $head = $doc->createElement('head');
            //add it to the bottom of the Crawler's node list
            $crawler->add($head);
            //grab the body
            $body = $crawler
                ->filter('body')
                ->first()
                ->getNode(0);
            //use insertBefore (http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php)
            //to get the head and put it above the body
            $body->parentNode->insertBefore($head, $body);
        }

echo $crawler->html();
```

yields

```
<head></head>
<body bgcolor="red"></body>
```

It seems a little convoluted but it works. I'm dealing with HTML but I imagine an XML solution would be nearly the same.

Comment: thank you for your response. I forgot for which project i had this problem, i solved it but i don't remember how. I remember that the code was clean and i think it was something almost similar than your code. Sorry it's been a long time and i've got memory problem in my brain, trying to allocate xxxx Ko

Comment: @VanIllaSkyPEPaPaCinO no worries, ha it'd be great if you could find your solution so I could compare it to mine!